# Add more workers to dataflow job on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

Im creating a dataprep flow that imports a CSV to BQ. This works fine but it takes too long time. Even for very small files. Is there a way to add more workers on the job? maxNumWorkers is always 1 by default.

Br 
Cris

Comment: How long does this usually take? What's a normal size for your CSV files? The reason I'm asking is that Dataflow and BQ have some fixed startup time of 3 minutes each (at least). If your files are very large, then it will be worth it to add more workers, but if not, then that 6-minute limit will be as low as you can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time that a Dataflow job was executed by Dataprep, the settings will be the default ones. However, you could re-run these jobs with different parameters directly from Dataflow by using its [templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/executing-templates#top_of_page). For instance, you could use the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/executing-templates#using-the-rest-api) and using the `numWorkers` field to specify the workers to execute the job, as it is unspecified, the service will attempt to choose a reasonable default. For more information regarding the REST API, you could review [this document](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/rest/v1b3/projects.jobs#workerpool).

Keep in mind that it has [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Run-Job-on-Cloud-Dataflow_99745844#known-limitations)